# Proofs for $n$-dimensional vector spaces $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space.

1. Prove that there is at most $n$ linearly independent elements in $V$.
2. Prove that a set of $m<n$ element in $V$ cannot span $V$.

I'm not really sure how to prove these, because as it makes sense to me, 1 is just the definition of "n"-dimensional and 2 is an application of that definition. If I say a space is $5$-dimensional, aren't I saying that the space has at most $5$ independent elements?

Answer (score 0):

Usually we define the dimension of a vector space to be the number of elements in a(ny) basis.  So in the first question, sure, any basis has $n$ elements by definition, but what about linearly independent collections of vectors which are not bases?